# Serve File from GAE Blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I have faced this problem several times that whenever we serve files from Blobstore API.
It is always downloaded as :

serve.fileNameExtention

is there any possible way that we can serve or download the file with the name we saved it.

i.e. someName.docx

If it is possible please tell me how to do it, because I have searched over internet but I couldn't found out any solution for it.

Comment: I have searched it all over then only I asked this.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob

Everywhere I got this solution only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it in header:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws IOException {
        BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key")); //example
        String filename = "someName.docx";
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" +fileName +\"");

        blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(key);                

BlobInfo blobInfo =  new BlobInfoFactory().loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
// set response header
response.setContentType(blobInfo.getContentType());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + blobInfo.getFilename());

// serve blob
blobService.serve(blobKey, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the file name in the url that you are serving the file from. You can use something like urlRewriteFilter (https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) to rewrite the urls to allow you to still use the "serve" servlet, but change the urls on their way out of the servlet to whatever you want them to be.

Comment: Well Sir, the serve method only accepts the blobKey so we cannot do anything with the name of the file.